# OAuth Echo TwitPic — Working with a Twitter client on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, twitpic

Hey everyone, I've been trying to get Twitpic to work successfully in uploading a picture through my iPhone app. This has worked fine in the past however now they've changed all their auth code.

This is what I've got, and for some reason is just giving me a failure:

```
oAuth = [[OAuth alloc] initWithConsumerKey:twitter_consumer_key andConsumerSecret:twitter_consumer_secret];

    NSString *fakeurl = @"https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json";
    NSString *oauth_header = [oAuth oAuthHeaderForMethod:@"GET" andUrl:fakeurl andParams:nil];
    NSLog(@"OAuth header : %@\n\n", oauth_header);

    NSString *url = @"http://api.twitpic.com/2/upload.json";

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"ASIHTTPRequest"];
    request.requestMethod = @"GET";

    [request addRequestHeader:@"X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization" value:oauth_header];    
    [request addRequestHeader:@"X-Auth-Service-Provider" value:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json"];   

    if (_imageData) {
        NSLog(@"Pic not nil");
    }

    [request setData:_imageData forKey:@"media"];
    [request setPostValue:@""  forKey:@"message"];  
    [request setPostValue:twitpic_api_key  forKey:@"key"];  

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];

    [request start];
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Twitter has been up and down so much that it's possible you're only getting an error because TwitPic can't pass along your verify credentials request.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can check the error.. I just know it's giving a failure by running "requestFailed:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use http://github.com/Gurpartap/GSTwitPicEngine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the delegate failed method is passed the request instance. You should query it to find out what values it has to make sure you've got everything set properly. [It has a flag that can be set to dump a debug string of the request.](http://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/blob/master/Classes/ASIFormDataRequest.h)

The first step in troubleshooting these kinds of problems is to make sure that the string you're submitting to the server is correct. Try submitting it through a browser and make sure it works because trying to construct it in code.